# Copy few columns from one sheet and insert at the end on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel and is learning to create formulas. 
Recently, I get a situation where I need to create a macro in which after clicking on "Update" button it copies few columns of a specific row in a sheet and insert these copied columns to another sheet in last line.

Example:
Following is the data in one sheet (GUI):

[image: GUI Sheet - Sheet1]

From this data, I would like to read all the yellow highlighted data and would like to insert it to another sheet (DataTogether) at the end:
[image: DataTogether - Sheet2]

Above read values need to be inserted to the yellow highlighted fields in 2nd sheet. Rest all remains bank.

Scenario:
From the data displayed in sheet one, when I press update button the it will read all the highlighted but will insert  data to sheet two where value in column J is passed.
i.e, values in row 11 and 13 will be read and inserted in sheet 2.

After insert operation the data in sheet 2 will add following two highlighted new rows (row 15 and 16):
[image: FinalOuput Image]

Please let me know if any other detail is required.

I hope I will learn some basics soon and will not post these types of queries again.

Many thanks in advance.

I tried to work and created a code in which it inserts the data at the line I hard coded, however I need to insert data in next available blank line.
I am not able to find a way to achieve it.

Please help.

I created following code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("GUI").Range("J7").Value) Then
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("G17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D4").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("N17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L2").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("B17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("C17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("C7").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("H17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D7").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("O17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("J7").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L7").Value
End If

If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("GUI").Range("J8").Value) Then
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("G17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D4").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("N17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L2").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("B17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("C17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("C8").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("H17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D8").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("O17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("J8").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L8").Value
End If

If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("GUI").Range("J9").Value) Then
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("G17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D4").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("N17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L2").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("B17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("C17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("C9").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("H17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D9").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("O17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("J9").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L9").Value
End If

If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("GUI").Range("J10").Value) Then
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("G17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D4").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("N17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L2").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("B17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("C17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("C10").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("H17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D10").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("O17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("J10").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L10").Value
End If

' First One Created
If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("GUI").Range("J11").Value) Then
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("G17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D4").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("N17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L2").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("B17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("C17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("C11").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("H17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D11").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("O17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("J11").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L11").Value
End If

If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("GUI").Range("J12").Value) Then
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("G17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D4").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("N17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L2").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("B17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("C17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("C12").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("H17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D12").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("O17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("J12").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L12").Value
End If

If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("GUI").Range("J13").Value) Then
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("G18").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D4").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("N18").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L2").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("B18").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("C18").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E18").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("C13").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("H18").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D13").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("O18").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("J13").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K18").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L13").Value
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: "Please let me know if any other detail is required" - including your current  attempt at the code as part of the question would be a good start.  (You won't learn anything if you don't try.)

Comment: Hello @YowE3K, I have updated the main query with the code I worked upon. I am stuck to enter the data in next available blank line. Currently I am harcoding the line number where I want to insert the data. Please help in it. Thanks.

Comment: try using a variable to get the last available line in the sheet2 then add the values to a new line. `lr=worksheets("GUI").Range("C1:C" & Rows.Count).end(xlup).row` this will give you the last row in the sheet "GUI". you can add 1 to value of lr and add the values there.

Comment: @SivaprasathV Thank you. It helped to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could help someone else, so posting answer here:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

LastRow = Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("GUI").Range("J7").Value) Then
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("G" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D4").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("N" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L2").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("C7").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("H" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D7").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("O" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("J7").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L7").Value
End If

LastRow = Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("GUI").Range("J8").Value) Then
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("G" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D4").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("N" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L2").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("C8").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("H" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D8").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("O" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("J8").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L8").Value
End If

LastRow = Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("GUI").Range("J9").Value) Then
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("G" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D4").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("N" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L2").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("C9").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("H" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D9").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("O" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("J9").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L9").Value
End If

LastRow = Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("GUI").Range("J10").Value) Then
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("G" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D4").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("N" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L2").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("C10").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("H" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D10").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("O" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("J10").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L10").Value
End If

LastRow = Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
' First One Created
If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("GUI").Range("J11").Value) Then
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("G" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D4").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("N" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L2").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("C11").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("H" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D11").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("O" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("J11").Value
    'Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K17").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L11").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L11").Value
End If

LastRow = Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("GUI").Range("J12").Value) Then
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("G" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D4").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("N" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L2").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("C12").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("H" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D12").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("O" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("J12").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L12").Value
End If

LastRow = Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("GUI").Range("J13").Value) Then
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("G" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D4").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("N" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L2").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("B" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("C" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("B7").Value 'Same for All
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("E" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("C13").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("H" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("D13").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("O" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("J13").Value
    'Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K18").Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L13").Value
    Worksheets("DataTogether").Range("K" & LastRow).Value = Worksheets("GUI").Range("L13").Value
End If


End Sub
```